# comobject InternetExplorer.Application: Start Multiple Browsers in own Session

Tags: internet-explorer, session, com, powershell

When opening two IE Windows in Powershell both will have the same Session/ProcessID
Is there a Switch to force a new Session/ProcessID for each Window?

```
    1..2 |
ForEach-Object {
$ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application  
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.google.de/")
}
```

With IE native Itself you can either Click on File > Rightclick > New Session

Or when Calling the iexplore.exe this will work with the -nomerge flag. Hope there is a way to achieve this with the ComObject.

> "C:\Program Files\Internet
>   Explorer\iexplore.exe" –nomerge